# What is the best way to generate a popup when user goes to leave site

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, mouseevent

I created a form that I am wanting to only appear if the user goes to leave the site. I searched to find a function for this and the closest one I could find was mouseleave.

It works well - at least on a desktop (haven't checked mobile yet) except there is one issue. I want the popup to appear only once. Right now it appears every time the mouse goes outside the body.

So, with this in mind, I am trying to figure out if there is a better approach to this.

The perfect solution would not use body, instead it would detect when the user goes to the browser tabs/search bar in the browser. I wasn't sure what to put, so body seemed like a decent starting point.

Is there also a way to limit this to working one time?

I couldn't get the snippet to function correctly, so feel free to view it on my test site.

```js
$('body').mouseleave(function() {
  $('#specialPop').fadeIn(350);
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e) {
  var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
  $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
  $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#specialPop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}

.popSpecialClose {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 33px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="specialPop" data-popup="popSpecial">
  <a class="popSpecialClose" data-popup-close="popSpecial" href="#">
  Close
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clearly define what you consider "leaving the site".  If I go to another tab is that leaving the site?  If I naviagate away from the page in the same tab to another page, is that leaving the site?

Comment: @Taplar Basically anytime the user moves their mouse cursor goes to the browser tabs at the top, when they are hovering over, so it catches them before they leave. I need it to happen only once though, not every time.

Comment: That seems very heavy handed.  What if I'm just leaving the window to open my calculator?  I'm not leaving your site.  I'm still looking at it.

Comment: @Taplar Any other ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the answer below.  Typically "leaving the site" is defined by navigating away from it.

Comment: @Taplar The answer below isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.beforeunload`, not `mouseleave`.

```js
$('window').on("beforeunload",function() {
  $('#specialPop').fadeIn(350);
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
  var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
  $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
  $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#specialPop {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 color: #FFF;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999999;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 display: none;
}
.popSpecialClose {
 position: absolute;
 right: 40px;
 top: 20px;
 width: 33px;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="specialPop" data-popup="popSpecial">
 <a class="popSpecialClose" data-popup-close="popSpecial" href="#">
  Close
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing is happening now. I tried closing a tab, going to a different tab, and taking the mouse off the page.